# How to get a list of authorized databases for the current account in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using a non-admin account to access to a Mongo instance. And the account I am using doesn't have the right to run `show dbs` command. And that account also doesn't have the permission to access `admin` database. See below output:

```
show dbs
2017-02-08T15:40:54.651+1100 E QUERY    [main] Error: listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:62:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:755:19
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:645:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

I wander how to get the list of databases this account has access. I know that I can use admin account to get all roles information. But I don't have admin account password. I only have this account credential. How can I do that for the specific account in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As at MongoDB 3.4, it is not possible for an authenticated user to view a full (or partial) list of accessible databases without a role that has the [`listDatabases`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/) admin privilege.

If you have access to an administrative account for your deployment (or can make a request of someone who does), one option would be to create a [create a custom role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createRole/) granting only this privilege. However, this does enable some potential information disclosure in a shared system since the `listDatabases` output currently includes all database names as well as their size on disk.

For example, to create a user `bobbytables` who can list all databases but only has read/write access to `webscale` and `xkcd` databases:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
    user: "bobbytables",
    pwd:  "drop;mic",
    roles: [
        { role: "readWrite", db: "webscale" },
        { role: "readWrite", db: "xkcd" }
    ]
})
db.createRole({
    role: "listDatabases",
    privileges: [
        { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "listDatabases" ] }
    ],
    roles: []
})
db.grantRolesToUser("bobbytables", ["listDatabases"])
```

There is a relevant open feature request to watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-6898: Allow all authenticated users to run listDatabases](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6898). The suggested change is to allow all users to run `listDatabases`, but have the result list filtered to databases where the current user has read or write privileges.